# Adding a new component to a DatetimeVector in Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

I would appreciate if someone could help me in push_back a new component into `DatetimeVector`. A `DatetimeVector` only has begin, end, `getDatetimes` and size methods.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say don't.  For multiple reasons:

1. *All* Rcpp types uses an underlying `SEXP` which requires contiguous memory. So adding a single element always requires copying all--expensive.
2. The `DatetimeVector` class is pretty bad. I wrote it many years ago to pass data to QuantLib.
3. These days we can do better via simple `NumericVector` classes to `POSIXct` -- see eg here in [Rblpapi](https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/blpapi_utils.cpp#L406-L412)

Comment: Hi Dirk, First of all, I deeply appreciate your active participation in Rcpp interactions. I have a DataFrame which has several columns of Datetime type. If I want to add a row to the end, I need to add date as well. I need to fix this problem probably by some as<>() and wrap() commands.